# Translate ImageView across screen with gyroscope feedback causes flickering image

Tags: android, animation, imageview, translate

What I'm trying to do is move an object across the screen based on how much the device has been rotated. In the activity, the OnSensorChanged calls a setPosition() method on the object I created (whose attributes include the ImageView I want to move).
The setPosition method is:

```
void setPosition(float degree) { //degree = total number of degrees the device has rotated
    float baseDegree = degree%360;
    TranslateAnimation transAm;

    if(baseDegree >= 0 && baseDegree < 90)
    {
        transAm = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, this.y,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, (float)(maxY) - ((baseDegree*maxX)/360)); //maxX = screenWidth
        transAm.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        transAm.setFillAfter(true);
        //transAm.setFillEnabled(true); // I tried all of these solutions
        //transAm.setDuration(1);       // I found online, but none seemed
        //transAm.setRepeatCount(1);    // to work.
        this.y = (float)(maxY) - ((baseDegree*maxY)/90);
        this.image.startAnimation(transAm);
    }
}
```

note MaxX is the screen width, and MaxY is the screen height.

The issue is the image seems to flicker rapidly between where it's supposed to be, and ~1/4 of the way to where it should be. I'm not sure how to get it to stay in one spot, and don't know if I could be calling too many animations on the image too many quickly, so I am open to other suggestions too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was just a typo.

```
Animation.ABSOLUTE, (float)(maxY) - ((baseDegree*maxX)/360));
```

should have just been

```
Animation.ABSOLUTE, (float)(maxY) - ((baseDegree*maxY)/90));
```